# Ardruino control for heating element

Tags: transistors

I am doing a project that requires me to control the heating element (as shown below 12V 100W). It's a PWM control from the Ardruino through a BJT transistor to control the MOSFET to the element.
My problem is the calculations for the resistors to use. With what I have done so far is to say that R1=100k\$\Omega\$ and R2=3k\$\Omega\$, but I do not know if that is correct or if there is a better layout to use. Using the [S8050](https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/149/SS8050-117753.pdf) and [IRFZ44N](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irfz44npbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153563b3a9f220d).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f58yOZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: FETs are voltage driven, BJTs are current driven. You really just need to ensure your Vgs goes below the threshhold. So as long as we saturate the BJT you're fine. A 3K resistor for R2 gives you 11.5V (12 - Vcesat from datasheet)/3K or 4mA. This is way lower than the max Ic of 1.5A. Saturation occurs when the base current is 4mA/100 (hfe) = 40uA. The way R1 is sized now you have 5-1.2(Vbesat) = 3.8V/100k = 38uA. So right now, this will work. You would only need to change things around if you care about speed. Depends on what your PWM frequency/duty cycle is.

Answer (score 1):

I'll expand a bit on computation in the comment from Stiddily.

Ignoring switching speed issues, the value of R1 should be chosen a) large enough that the current is smaller than that maximum rating of the Arduino, and b) small enough that the current is large enough to saturate the transistor.

**To compute the minimum R1 value**

The Arduino pin will go to 5 V or 3.3 V depending on how you power it, and I think the recommended maximum sustained current is 20 mA. At saturation, the transistor base-emitter will drop 1.2 V (from datasheet). So to stay under 20 mA with the 5 V supply, you should use (from Ohm's law) at least 190 Ω, but because it's not so critical, I'd use at least 1 kΩ, which will give about 4 mA (or 2 mA if you use 3.3 V)

**To compute the minimum R2 value**

The R2 value should be large enough the current going through it and the transistor is within safe limits in saturation.

The transistor drops 0.5 V in saturation (from datasheet) so the voltage drop across the resistor is 11.5 V. The maximum collector current rating of the transistor is 1.5 A. In that case the resistor would also dissipate about 17 Watts of power and probably catch fire very quickly, so the limiting factor is the power rating of the resistor.

Using a normal 1/4 W resistor, we'd like to have at most 1/8 W of power dissipation in R2. Using P=UI and Ohm's law, we find that about 1 kΩ will keep us in that limit and give a 11 mA current. So R2 should be at least 1 kΩ, but can be a little bit bigger too.

**To compute the maximum R1 value**

It depends on the chosen R2 value. Using the simple transistor equation Ic = h * Ib, we want R1 to be small enough that the base current Ib is larger than Ic/h. Using a conservative value of h = 100, and the 11 mA above, the base current has to be at least 110 µA. With the smaller 3.3 V supply (and the transistor drop), this means at most 19 kΩ in R1, but that's already very high.

So all in all, your R2 should be at least 1 kΩ but can be a bit higher. Your R1 depends on your R2, but with that smallest R2 value, it can be something between 250 Ω and 19 kΩ. Lower values are generally better for switching speed. I'd personally use 1 kΩ for R1 and maybe something like 1–5 kΩ for R2.

Answer (score 0):

I would size R1 more in the 3.3K to 4.7K range to ensure that the transistor is fully saturated. Using very high resistors on the base of the NPN makes your circuit much more susceptible to noise which can be prevalent in a power switching application.

The value of R2 will determine how fast the N-FET turns on because when the NPN turns off this resistor has to charge the gate capacitance to get the FET to turn on. You can start with your 3K value but once you start driving this circuit with your PWM signal you should check the waveforms with an oscilloscope to ensure that the time constant of the gate drive signal does not cause a significant distortion of the PWM signal duty cycle seen at the load. If there is distortion then lower the R2 value to bring it into a more acceptable level.